# The sum of pure submodules of noncommutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be an arbitrary noncommutative ring, and let $A$ and $B$ be pure submodules of $R$. Is the sum $A+B$ a pure submodule of $R$?

I feel it is not, but I could not find out a counterexample.